# a question on using Microsoft Excel to do data analysis

Tags: excel

Me and my mates have been given an Excel spreasheet,which contains the data of the Census report.
The column here corresponds to "Year" (from 2000-2010),the row means "City/Town",the cell is simply the population of a town at a particular year.
We are up to doing some analysis like “what town had its first population gain in 10 years?”
etc.My question is just about can we do this in Excel,or do we need to export the data to other database(SQL) then do the programming?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know that you can implement custom functions in excel, don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that specific piece of data analysis

```
{=AND(SUM(--((C2:K2-B2:J2)>0))=0,L2>K2)}
```

Don't enter the curly braces, enter the formula with Control+Shift+Enter.

But if you're more comfortable in SQL, then you should import it into a database and work with it that way.  Put it where you have the best skill set and you'll get the job done the quickest.

Comment: Thanks Dick
I am considering doing the exporting thing since I am more comfortable with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in Excel. That answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a substantial amount in excel, both by simply using the facilities provided as cell functions, and if that doesn't suffice, you can use VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) built into excel for more complex analysis.